# .on() .off() or .one() logic to stop repeat clicking on list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a [JSFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/VFqTW/27/).

I would like to remove repeat clicking because the clicks create an animation.

I understand now that `$(this).off('click');` will do the trick; however,

Where I run into problems is how can I turn `.on()` the click after any new listitem has been clicked.

Also noted, `.one()` seems to be a good solution; however, I'm unsure on how to use this while maintaining my same symantics.  Thank you.

```
var carItems = $('.carousel_item');
var sideitems = $('.side_item');
var x = false;
$(sideitems).hide();
fadeItem();
$(carItems).on({
    click: function() {
        $(sideitems).stop(true, true).animate({
            right: '4.5em'
        });
        $(sideitems).hide();
        fadeItem();
    },
    mouseenter: function() {},
    mouseleave: function() {}
});

function fadeItem() {
    $('.side_ul li:hidden:first').fadeIn(fadeItem).animate({
        right: '-4.5em'
    }, 150, function() {});;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide1_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide2_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide1_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide2_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
      </ul>
    </div>

      <nav class="side_nav">
    <ul class="side_ul">
        <li class="side_item home"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">home</a></div></li>
        <li class="side_item document"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">docs</a></div></li>
        <li class="side_item video"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">video</a></div></li>        
        <li class="side_item programming"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">web</a></div></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: So each of the li's that you click on are animating the same slide-in menu, or different slide-in menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5A6Xn/

Using a combination of on() and off(), you can modify the class attributes to achieve your results:

```
 var carItems = $('.carousel_item');
 var sideitems = $('.side_item');
 var x = false;
 $(sideitems).hide();
 fadeItem();

 bindClick();

 function bindClick()
 {
     $(".carousel_item:not(.selected)").on("click", function(event)
     {
         $(".carousel_item").off("click");
         $('.carousel_item').removeClass("selected");    
         $(this).addClass("selected");
         $(sideitems).stop(true, true).animate({
             right: '4.5em'
         });
         $(sideitems).hide();

         fadeItem();

         bindClick();
     });
 }

 $(carItems).on({     
     mouseenter: function () {

     },
     mouseleave: function () {

     }
 });

 function fadeItem() {
     $('.side_ul li:hidden:first').fadeIn(fadeItem).animate({
         right: '-4.5em'
     }, 150, function () {});;
 }
```

Comment: Problem with this is that I would like the list items to be rebound clickable after the following element has been clicked.  if i mash 1 the animation will be excutedonce... if I then mash 2 the animation will be excuted only once.  But then I can go back and mash 1 again and it will trigger the animation.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I did not understand that from your post. I've modified the fiddle to do what you need it to do. It is a new URL and I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking for the element being animated (`$(el).is(':animated')`) and then removing the click like so:

```
$(elementClickedOn).click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: where and how would I incorperate this? could you add it to the jsfiddles?

Comment: Using same symantics how would I use this line of code ?  I want to remove the click but I want to add it back on when the next element it clicked